# Python fabric nested roles

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to understand how to use nested `roledefs` in fabric. [It](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#roles) is written,

> Role definitions are not necessary configuration of hosts only, but
>   could hold other role specific settings of your choice. This is
>   achieved by defining the roles as dicts and host strings under a hosts
>   key

My config is like,

```
from fabric.api import env
env.roledefs = {
    'prod': {
        'hosts': ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3'],
        'db': ['db1']
    },
}
```

My question is how to access `db` for a particular task.

```
@roles('db') or @roles('prod')  #<- not sure what to add here
def migrate():
    # migration stuff
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
roles = {'prod': {'hosts': ['node1', 'node2'], 'db': ['node3']}
         'test': {'hosts': ['test1'], 'db': ['test2']}}

def migrate(role='test'):
    env.roledefs = roles[role]
    execute(_run_prepare)
    execute(_run_migrate)

@roles('hosts', 'db')
def _run_prepare():
    pass # runs on hosts in role "hosts" and hosts in role "db"

@roles('db')
def _run_migrate():
    pass # runs on hosts in role "db"
```